# Confirm Form Resubmission - Page Data expired after page postback in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, caching, sitecore, sitecore7.2

I am developing **CMS web application** using ASP.Net .ascx page and Getting Templates from **Sitecore**. On one of the pages I did the manual pagination using Link buttons eg. prev : Next. While clicking next button once and click some other button and navigate to other page. After that I try to come previous page using browser back button I am getting "**Confirm Form Resubmission**" error. What i understand while page getting postback **page data get expired**. Any option I am missing in web.config or application??

Comment: Could you post some code? If the error is an exception the complete message could be helpful.

Comment: Hi Daniel, There no specific code , over all application i am getting same  "Confirm Form Resubmission" in chrome after postback page and redirect to some other page. Can able under stand in which scenario i am getting error. ** Note ** : After click browser back button there no response going to previous page.

Comment: I'm wild guessing that one of your button is causing a form post :). Maybe the propperty UseSubmitBehavior? Good luck, maybe post some more code so we can help :)!.

Comment: _"While clicking next button once and click some other button and navigate to other page"_ Your issue is here somewhere. Clicking buttons usually triggers postbacks, which submits a form which is what your message is warning you about.